# How do I fetch data between multiple scenes through a menu

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with a main menu, one interface where you can do some math stuff to get a string with a result number. I want this number to be used in another formula in another view, which is not directly linked to this view.

All the stuff I found on how to pass data on is using prepareForSegue, but as I don't have a segue between this scene and the scene I want the number in, I don't see how I could get use of this method.

What would be the best way to do this? Make some sort of database and fetch data from here? Some method? I'm not too experienced with programming, so detailed answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using storyboard to manage view transitions?

Comment: you can always use @property-@synthesize methods. Try that.

Comment: @KerrM Yes, using storyboard.

Comment: I would update your question with more specific details, e.g. how are you creating the view? How are you transitioning from one view to another? If you aren't using segues, then are you creating the view programmatically and using `pushViewController`?

Comment: Im using segues, just not directly between the two views i want to pass data between. My views are created in xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use user defaults for your string.

```
// store
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myString 
    forKey:@"globalMathString"];

// retrieve
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   objectForKey:@"globalMathString"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what I wanted. But, when implementing this, i get 
`NSString *getData = [[NSUserDefaults]* standardUserDefaults]
objectForKey:@"globalMathString"];
    testLabel.text = getData;
` 
error at NSuserdefaults, where the star is. Error is "Expected identifier"

Comment: Sorry for the typo :-( - Corrected.